# Generate table with OpenTBS - each row in separate cell

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I try to create an ODT file (or docx) with table inside. I read and search all SO and support forum but have no idea how to make something like this:

```
cell1.val1  |  cell2.val1  |  cell3.val1
cell1.val2  |  cell2.val2  |  cell3.val2
cell1.val3  |  cell2.val3  |  cell3.val3
------------|--------------|------------
cell4.val1  |  cell5.val1  |  cell6.val1
cell4.val2  |  cell5.val2  |  cell6.val2
cell4.val3  |  cell5.val3  |  cell6.val3
----------------------------------------`
```

and so on, and on...
I don't know how to build the array and how to create a template for it. If someone has a similar solution and could help with it I will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two merges in your table: merging the different cells in the table and merging items in a cell.

For merging the different cells in the table you can merge a block with option `serial` .
See [example](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=prmserial&m=result) and [doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_serial).

For merging the items in a cell, you can use a sub-block. The simplest are « automatic sub-blocks ».
See [example](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=subblock&m=result) and [doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_subblock).

So if your data are structured like this :

```
$data = array(
   array(
    'cell_id' => 1,
    'items' => array(
        array('value' => 1),
        array('value' => 2),
        array('value' => 3),
        // ...
    ),
   ),
   array(
    'cell_id' => 2,
    'items' => array(
        array('value' => 1),
        // ...
    ),
   ),
   ...
);
```

then your template can be like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Column 1                                | Column 2                                | Column 3                                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [b;block=tbs:row;serial]                |                                         |                                         |
| [b_1.cell_id;block=tbs:cell;sub1=items] | [b_2.cell_id;block=tbs:cell;sub1=items] | [b_3.cell_id;block=tbs:cell;sub1=items] |
| [b_1_sub1.value;block=tbs:p]            | [b_2_sub1.value;block=tbs:p]            | [b_3_sub1.value;block=tbs:p]            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this example, items in a cell are merged on a paragraph (`block=tbs:p`) assuming that the TBS fields is placed in its own paragraph. You can also use a nested table, then you have to specify `block=tbs:row`.

Comment: many thanks for helping. I try to managed with the `serial` example, but when I copied `PHP Programm` and set `Template Source` codes inside ODT file I get this error `TinyButStrong Error in block's definition [bx...]: at least one tag corresponding to tr is not found. Check opening tags, closing tags and embedding levels.` and can't figured out what wrong. In example everything goes well... ODT is down.

Comment: for more details about template here's screenshot of ODT file https://imgur.com/a/hKftJ and here's a php programm code https://pastebin.com/VgVq20rd

Comment: OK, GOT IT! Tags inside ODT file was wrong. I changed `block` prefixes to `tbs` and set correct names for td and tr which should be named cell and row in tbs. So for now I get what I want